# "Trim" right zeroes from integral type

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, numbers

How to fast remove trailing zeroes from an integer NOT using strings?

For example, `1000` must become `1`, `6789000` must become `6789`.

Easy solution is repeatedly taking modulo of division by `10^max_exponent`, ..., `10000`, `1000`, `100`, `10` (or in reverse order) and so on and comparing it to `0`.

But can someone do it faster?

Comment: Pre-make a table mapping all numbers to their values with the trailing zeros removed.  So `table[1000] => 1`, `table[1001] => 1001`, `table[1010] => 101`, `table[6789000] => 6789`, `table[6789001] => 6789001`.  For any number N, just return the Nth entry out of the table.  Very fast.

Comment: @HostileFork what if max_number is of type int64_t, i.e. ~9*10^18? :)

Comment: @vladon - to be fair, his way is fast, which is what you asked for.

Comment: @Sean It is NOT fast if numbers count are more than memory cache size, because data read is slower than calculations in that case.

Comment: @vladon - I know, I was being sarcastic! Since you dont want lookup tables or div/mod to be used why not show us what you've come up with so far?

Comment: @Sean My algorithm is now as in third paragraph (in reverse order).

Comment: More context might help. If you represent each number in base 10 rather than the computer's native base 2, and an extra marker, you'll have an immediate answer. It would help to know the context and how the number will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially this is binary search by power of 10:

```
if N mod 100000000 = 0
  N = N div 100000000;
if N mod 10000 = 0  
  N = N div 10000;
if N mod 10000 = 0  
  N = N div 10000;
if N mod 100 = 0
  N = N div 100;
if N mod 10 = 0
  N = N div 10;
```

Comment: Isn't this solution the same as the one in the question, the solution which the OP is hoping to improve?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן  He uses all ten powers in order, 19 operations, but there is enough to make  Log2(19)=5 operations

Comment: Isn't the `second N mod 10000` redundant?

Comment: @erickson Not, it is needed to provide sum of powers = 19 ( for int64 range).

Comment: Okay, I was thinking 32 bits. Makes sense, and very similar to the Hacker's Delight solution for binary trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you take Log10 of the number you can figure out how many digits it has. Using this info you can start your division process at the smallest power of ten just greater than your number. You can then eliminate some of your mod tests and divisions. You could make a loop to simplify the code.

Pseudocode:

```
digit_count = log10(num) + 1
pow = 10^digit_count
for (int i = 0; i < digit_count; i++) {
    if (num mod pow == 0) {
      num /= pow
    }
    pow /= 10
}
return num
```